# javascript page refresh in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I am trying figure out how to refresh page in Safari (5.1) using javascript and nothing seems to work.

So far, I have tried,

- window.location.href = window.location.href
- window.location = window.location.href
- window.location.reload(true)
- window.location.replace(window.location.href)

What is the right way of handling page refresh in Safari?

Comment: all of them are working for me. I'm 5.0 Windows

Comment: Do you know how to open developer tools in Safari?

Comment: try document.location.reload(true)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, Safari on Mac or iOS has a bug with location.reload, so, I've developed this simple cross browser solution taking advantage of the url query string:

```html
function refresh() {
  var url = location.origin;
  var pathname = location.pathname;
  var hash = location.hash;

  location = url + pathname + '?application_refresh=' + (Math.random() * 100000) + hash;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
location.reload(true); // works for safari
```

If you didn't know already this site, let have a look on it, you will have a lot of example for refreshing page: http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_refresh_page.cfm

Comment: This didn't work for me, in a scenario where the page was a response from a POST.

Comment: For a POST what do you expect ? If you refresh a POST page, it will be more tricky.

Comment: Yep it is more tricky, but seems like an exception for Safari - rest of the browsers support a JS-based refresh of a `POST` request.

Comment: It works!!! life saver

Answer (score 2):

You should always use the [`reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#reload) method from the [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location) object...

```
window.location.reload();
```

Set the first argument to true if you want to *hard reload* (send a new GET request for the page).

Comment: This didn't work for me, in a scenario where the page was a response from a POST.

Comment: You shouldn't be rendering a response from POST, you should use [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). Otherwise you will have the same issues when a user tries to reload or navigate back to this page.

Comment: Definitely, in this scenario it should just be a GET with query string. But can't redesign right now, and also it does work - refresh, navigating back, and even `window.location.reload()` except for Safari. So I'm hoping for an alternative to `window.location.reload()` that is fully cross-browser, though I'm suspecting it doesn't exist.

Comment: @andrewb You can always do `window.location = window.location`

Comment: That still does a `GET` instead of a `POST` for Safari. Seems like it's redesign or nada for JS `POST` refresh in Safari.

Comment: @andrewb I would redesign, it sounds like you're trying to work around a problem already (rendering from a POST).

Comment: I'm so keen for redesign, but unfortunately budget doesn't allow for that. None of these `POST` requests are dangerous, so it's not a major problem.