# jquery $.post function not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript/jquery function I call as a link with an added attribute = symbol. It works perfect in Chrome, and it also gets the symbol attribute over to the alert message in the function - but does not execute in Safari.

The link calling the function looks like this

```
<a onclick=\"addStock(event);\" Symbol=$symbol>Add</a>
```

The javascript/jquery looks like this

```
    function addStock(event) {
        var element = event.target;
        var symbol = element.getAttribute("symbol");

        if (confirm("Add Symbol to Watchlist " + symbol + "?")) {
            $.post("watchlistinsert.php?symbol="+ symbol +"&price=25&watchlistgroupid=1");
            document.location.reload();
            console.log("item " + symbol + " added");
        } else {

            console.log("user canceled");
        }
        return;
    }
```

Any ideas what is wrong with the code/safari and how to get around it?

Comment: Are the backslashes escaping the double quotes in your onclick assignment actually part of your code? Or are they a copy/paste error?

Comment: It is like this <a onclick=\"addStock(event);\" Symbol='$symbol'>Add</a> and it works in Chrome - also now in Safari - but the  document.location.reload(); does not - if i remove this it works...

Comment: Remove the backslashes. They are not valid there. You need this: `<a onclick="addStock(event);" Symbol="$symbol">Add</a>`

Comment: Are you using a PHP echo statement to output the anchor element?

Comment: It works if i remove   document.location.reload(); - I then added a function after the $.Post to do the update - thanks guys, and it acutally works fine with everything else in all browsers as long as   document.location.reload(); is not included...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first error might be from custom attribute:

Try changing the attribute to this one: `Symbol='$symbol'`
Secondly have you tried adding a fake href attribute for example `href="#"` ?

What about debugging js code  ? Did you get any error in safari ?

I think different browser do behave differently when using `document` or `window` so I would recommend using the options below and see if any of them work:

1. `window.location.reload(true);`
2. `location.reload(true);`
3. `window.location.reload()`

If none of them work try to use this function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39300372/3769368)

Comment: Thanks - it works if i delete the document.location.reload(); part of the code - any ideas on this?

Comment: @PeterKroul see the edit answer :) I think it will solve the problem for safari as well

Comment: Sorry nothing of the both worked - I'm going to make a new question.